# How to fix "<ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp> not found"?

Tags: c++, macos, clion

I am trying to run a code taken from [here](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/knucleotide-gpp-2.html). I use CLion to run the code.
There is a compile error with:

`#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>`

as the file is not found.

Do I need to anything to the CMakeLists.txt or should I install anything?

There are similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666693/how-to-browse-classes-after-instantiation) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351676/why-does-gnu-pds-not-work-even-though-i-have-installed-gcc), none of which has got an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: What compiler (and standard library implementation) are you using to compile the code? This is a libstdc++-specific header. It is not standard C++. So probably you should make sure that you are using GCC to compile the code. (Maybe Clang with libstdc++ will also work, but not Apple Clang with libc++.)

Comment: @user17732522 I'm a bit confused by CLion settings. It doesn't show which compiler it uses by default. By the way, I'm using macOS and I have both gcc and g++ installed on my mac.

Comment: @plpm Make sure you _really_ have gcc/g++ installed and that you are using it (I can't help you with CLion setup, since I don't know anything about that.). Apple tends to just redirect `gcc` and `g++` commands to their version of clang, which won't support this. The second question you linked has the exact same problem. Unfortunately it seems to be a non-trivial issue to actually use GCC on mac.

Comment: @user17732522 I just tried to compile the code in the terminal by using gcc/g++ but it showed the same error.

Comment: @plpm As I said, on mac typically `gcc`/`g++` isn't really either, but instead just a link to `clang`/`clang++`. Try `which g++` and see where it points.

Comment: @user17732522 It displays `/usr/bin/g++`

Comment: @plpm And `ls -lah /usr/bin/g++`?

Comment: @plpm Chat isn't really worth it. I can't help you anymore anyway. I guess the command above will just show you that `/usr/bin/g++` is a link to clang and my knowledge about Apple products ends there.

Comment: @user17732522 Did you see this as well:
`-rwxr-xr-x 76 root wheel 163K 26 Mar 07:21 /usr/bin/g++`

Comment: @plpm OK, last try. What does `g++ --version` say?

Comment: @user17732522 
```Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: @plpm OK, there we have it: "Apple clang". You need a compiler that will actually tell you that it is "g++", not "Apple clang".

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you for your time. At least, the reason of the error is found now, which is very helpful.